# SQL Syntax error on code that worked on php my admin

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have the following code that works in phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Leaderboard2 (Player text, Score float)
```

When I run the same code in python (I want to be able to change the leaderboard):

```
make_leaderboard = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Leaderboard%s (Player text, Score float)")
cursor.execute(make_leaderboard, *Leaderboard_Number*)
```

It comes up with this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s (Player text, Score float)' at line 1
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `%s` on table name which will not work & create error in your sql best way to add variable as table name use `format` or `concate` string like this

```
make_leaderboard = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Leaderboard{num} (Player text, Score float)"
cursor.execute(make_leaderboard.format(num=Leaderboard_Number))
```

> Parameter substitution('%s') in the python DB API is only for values -
> not tables or fields.